# Failed to install the app in android emulator in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to run my react native CLI app in an android emulator but it getting errors to install in the emulator.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     E:\Program Files\React Native CLI\testDemo\android\CLI\testDemo\node_modules\react-native-image-crop-picker\android\build\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-14:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.
```

And already installed this dependency `react-native-image-crop-picker` in react native, I have perfectly set up the environment variables which are mentioned by Facebook. And this error is showing up

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
```

Manifest File has no error you see it
[image: Manifest file of the given location]
Kindly please what should I do to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you linked it using ```react-native link```

Comment: Seems like you have added something wrong in your android manifest (Maybe while adding permissions). could you please share your manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acording to [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/preparing-your-build-for-package-visibility-in-android-11.html) its look like known issue.Try to upgrade gradle and rebuild.

```
 buildscript 
{
    ...

   dependencies {
       // classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
     }

    ...
}
```